# How can you display the saving a customer makes from Catalog Price Rules on the Cart?

Tags: discount, catalog-price-rules, promotions, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm trying to find out if it even possible to display the amount of savings a customer makes on the cart from any active catalog price rules.

Scenario:
We have a customer group setup which has a 25% discount catalog price rule. It shows the discounted price and original price in the catalog, but in the cart it only shows the final (discounted) price. This doesn't give any indication of what the saving is they are getting.

Is there a way to display the saving, even if it requires a module?

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Comment: Hi Siarhey, it's version **1.9.2.4**

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas of even which direction I can look into to achieve a result? The other option for me is to out source to a Magento developer.

Comment: I had this solved by getting a developer to actually create the required functionality.